# Cancel pending publication in playconsole

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Hi how can I cancel a pending publication in PlayConsole and delete the pending application in PlayConsole ?

Comment: or is there any way to contact google support from here ?